# Android - Save big JSON to Realm OutOfMemoryException

Tags: android, json, out-of-memory, realm

### Situation:

I have a large `Json file` on my server *( >= 50-100Mb )* with the information of all customers I will need on my app.

I have to download the file into my application and save all the information to my `Realm` database. (there are nearly *200k objects in this file*).

### Customer.class

This is the object saved in this array:

```
public class Customer  extends RealmObject {
    public Customer(){}

    @PrimaryKey
    private String ID;
    private String FULL_NAME;
    private String PHONE_NO;
    private String CODICE_FISCALE;
    private Date MODIFIED_ON;

    //getters and setters
```

### My download and save code:

This is an `AsyncTask`, I removed all the useless code for an easier view

```
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        Realm realm = null;
        newSha = null;
        try {
            realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();

            String url = "myurl";
            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                    .connectTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .writeTimeout(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .readTimeout(120, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .build();

            Request request = new Request.Builder().url(url)
                    .addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json")
                    .build();

            Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
            ResponseBody responseBody = response.body();

            try {
                String myHeader = response.header("Content-Disposition");
                if (myHeader != null) {
                    int position = myHeader.indexOf("filename=");
                    position += "filename=".length();
                    newSha = myHeader.substring(position);
                }
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                newSha = null;
            }

            if (responseBody == null) {
                return null;
            }
            InputStream is = responseBody.byteStream();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
            final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
            }

            response.close();
            responseBody.close();
            is.close();
            reader.close();

            //switch because i have 20-30 cases, this is the big file which gives problems
            switch (fileName) {
                case "Customers": {
                    realm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
                        @Override
                        public void execute(Realm realm) {
                            try {
                                Log.wtf("SYNC", "Customer - start delete");
                                realm.delete(Customer.class);
                                Log.wtf("SYNC", "Customer - end delete, start create");  //this line is reached
                                realm.createAllFromJson(Customer.class, sb.toString());  
                                Log.wtf("SYNC", "Customer - end create");                //this line is never reached
                                setTitle(String.format("Completato! [%s]", title));

                                publishProgress(100, 1);
                                addSyncCompleted(false, null, null);
                                genericDbClass.setSHA(realm, new Customer(), newSha);
                            } catch (Exception error) {
                                newSha = null;                                            //this error is never thrown
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
                break;
```

### Problem:

The `realm.createAllFromJson` throws an `OutOfMemoryException` (not really thrown, the application just shut down with *no catch fired* and without any error. All I can see in the log are some exceptions like this logged as **Warn**

```
W/art: Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 170348044 byte allocation with 16777216 free bytes and 162MB until OOM"
```

The problem is on how to save this big Json file into Realm. I tried also to parse this string earlier with Gson but without any success. The file might increase size in time, so how can I speed this up?

Any help will be appreciated, I've been stuck on this for one week.

Comment: why don't you break the data and receive in you app?

Comment: @phpdroid sorry but I didn't understand, what do you mean by this? (I'm pretty new to streams and realm)

Comment: @PierGiorgioMisley instead of downloading all customers or all records at once, do paging, download first 20, and next 20 and next 20 and so on....

Comment: hey, am not using big words here just try something like Pagination to receive data I meant.

Comment: Ohh sorry I didn't realize that you meant it! thanks both.. I will try with it! going to google some ways for doing it

Comment: If you can't make a pre-shipped Realm with the data, then you'll need to cut the data up into batches of transactions instead of 1 transaction. While typically you should try to do things in 1 transaction, there is a maximum limit, see https://github.com/realm/realm-core/issues/2614

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Realm has a streaming variant of `createAllFromJson()` that accepts an `InputStream` directly: https://realm.io/docs/java/3.7.1/api/io/realm/Realm.html#createAllFromJson-java.lang.Class-java.io.InputStream-

This should also prevent you from running out of memory.

Comment: I still can't figure out how I didn't see this.. thanks for your great work with realm!